# How to sort the symbol table (generated by "objdump -t") sequentially by address?

Tags: c, symbols, objdump, arm-none-eabi-gcc

I would like to see at one glance which variables are placed next to each other in memory.
If I generate a symbol table by using `objdump -t` I get the symbol table, however sorted seemingly randomly.

```
SYMBOL TABLE:
00100584 l     F .text  00000000 deregister_tm_clones
001005a8 l     F .text  00000000 register_tm_clones
001005d4 l     F .text  00000000 __do_global_dtors_aux
0019c020 l       .bss   00000001 completed.10177
0019c00c l     O .fini_array    00000000 __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
00100604 l     F .text  00000000 frame_dummy
0019c024 l       .bss   00000018 object.10182
0019c008 l     O .init_array    00000000 __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 tcp_server_test.c
0019c03c l       .bss   00000004 xServerWorkTaskHandle
001006a4 l     F .text  00000098 prvServerWorkTask
0019c040 l       .bss   00000008 xMyTelnet
...
```

Is there a way to get it sorted by address (first column) in upcounting manner?

It would be great if there was a switch that could be added to `objdump -t` to get the desired output. I looked through the documentation and did not find anything like that, but maybe I overlooked something?

Another approach could be to write a python script that resorts it, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try a simple call of "sort"?

Comment: @the busybee Yesss that did it!! Great, thank you! :D
If you write it as answere I will accept it as solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the universal tool "sort" to sort the output of "objdump".

Please read its documentation for options. Without any option, it simply sorts on the first column.

---

For the no-yet-enlightened command line user...

You need to "pipe" the output of "objdump" as input into "sort" like this:

`objdump -t my_module.o | sort`

Comment: Sort on first column is perfect for this application, you don't need any additional switches, except maybe for -n to tell it to sort numerical values.

Comment: Does this also works on windows? What's the solution in windows?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd Why didn't you simply try it? At least Win10 on the currently used machine knows a tool of the same name.

Comment: @thebusybee `sort(arm-none-eabi-objdump ANC_fxlms_v1.elf -t)` doesnn't work in Win10.

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd You might want to refresh your knowledge of command line usage; see my edit. -- Oh, and "_does not work_" is not a helpful statement. ;-) You might want to post an own question, if you have a serious issue. SO is not a forum.